# How to override material CSS styles?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I use Angular Material 2.

There is one CSS style in material CSS:

```
.mat-radio-button.mat-accent .mat-radio-inner-circle {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

I tried to override it in custom CSS file like:

```
.mat-radio-button.mat-accent .mat-radio-inner-circle {   background-color: red !important; }
```

Also I tried this:

```
/deep/ .mat-radio-button.mat-accent .mat-radio-inner-circle {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

It does not work, how to do this right and in which place?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You do it in your global style sheet (`style.scss`), or in any style sheet that is **not** encapsulated.

To override, take the selector by inspecting the HTML element in your browser, and override the property you want.

If it still fails, you can use `!important` to force the style to be applied.

Remember to order your style sheet imports in your `angular.json` file too (thank you @SurenSrapyan for reminding me)

Answer (score 6):

In the angular configuration file you need to import your styles after materialize styles

Comment: If we do this, then we do not have to use !important.

Comment: @Dacili Not really. You need to look at the strength of the styles also

Comment: @suren-srapyan Where in `angular.json` are the Material styles imported? I have 1 item in the `styles` property which is my `src/styles.scss` file.

Comment: @Jack You need to import them manually, it is not imported automatically

Comment: I'm using the Angular Material framework, so it is imported automatically (or at least appears to be). Can you point me to where the material css files are imported?

Answer (score 1):

The best practice to override the other file CSS is to make it more specific. And these will work everywhere.

Here is a blog link, to get detail study of CSS specificity:
https://medium.com/@kastor012/the-basic-guide-to-css-specificity-b89726c0c0bc

Just like if you want to override you above code i.e.

```
.mat-radio-button.mat-accent .mat-radio-inner-circle {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Then, you must add your class within the element or parent to it.
and write the specified CSS to override it as:

```
.my__parent__class .mat-radio-button.mat-accent .mat-radio-inner-circle {
  background-color: #fff;
}

OR

.my__element__class.mat-radio-button.mat-accent .mat-radio-inner-circle {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As deep: has been deprecated you can refer below answer too.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63389535/14097555